# Lock Orientation iMessenger App?

Tags: swift, user-interface, orientation, swift3, imessage

Is it possible to lock the orientation of an iMessenger App (iOS 10)?

I've tried using the .plist file to set the supported orientations but it doesn't work. I want to restrict the orientation to portrait but when I delete the landscape orientations from the .plist, the app still rotates.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. Apple has clearly said in the last WWDC that they want dev to support both orientations.